# Internal Server 500 Error Sharing Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-document-library

In SharePoint online we have a need to share a document library with the "Everyone" group without granting permissions to the entire site.  We're using the modern document interface, and the explicit sharing part of this works just fine.

When the user opens the document library, click on the file, open the information panel, the preview begins to render but then quickly resolves to a 500 Internal Server Error.  This happens for any user who does not have full access to the site and on all file types.

I would really prefer to not have to change all of the other permissions on the objects in this site just to give access to this modern document library to the Everyone group.

Does anyone have an idea what else I may need to grant read permissions on to avoid this internal server error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our organization ended up opening a support ticket with Microsoft to help with this problem.  We didn't necessarily correct the issue, but we tracked it back to a custom site column that had a calculated default value associated with it.  The column was setting a default value for the current Fiscal Year based on the current date.  For some reason if the user did not have at a minimum site-level access the page would return the Internal 500 Server error.

To work around this we simply removed the default calculated value for this particular document library that needs to be shared out to the "Everyone" group.